# "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request" When creating a role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a command that creates a role, this is the code:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def createrole(ctx, * name):
  guild = ctx.guild
  await guild.create_role(name=name)
```

But when I run it, it tells me this:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In name: Could not interpret "[New Role]" as string.
```

Comment: You forgot a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting a valid name, You have an extra space between `*` and `name`.

Please read more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#variable)

```py
@client.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def createrole(ctx, *name):
  await ctx.guild.create_role(name=name)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it